# Akka: factors to consider when designing Actor organization structure?

Tags: java, akka

I'm using Java 8 to build a web service client which leverages `TimerBasedThrottler`. What factors should I consider when designing the Actor organizational model?

I'm currently considering;

1. Complexity
2. Throughput
3. Potential for blocking

My current design uses the following organizational structure;

```
-  RequestCoordinator (Master) singleton
-----   TimerBasedThrottler (Delegator) singleton
----------              RequestSender (Worker) - one actor created per web service request
```

Incoming requests are passed through the throttler which enforces a particular TPS. The throttler and coordinator are both singletons. Then individual actors are used to send each request. These actors are passed to the throttler and issue poison pill messages once they complete their work.

The use of routers is promoted for Akka Actors; can this improve the design I have outlined above and make it more fault tolerant and performant? Mine is a simple use case however I want to explore how I can improve the design using Akka principles?

Answer (score 2):

In general: encourage hierarchical structures and observe the Error Kernel Pattern which in essence pushes the riskier tasks to leaf nodes.

Secondly, I would recommend considering using `context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce` for the `PoisonPill` messages if you aren't already. This can greatly simplify implementation (mostly an aside, not necessarily directed at anything in your post).

Furthermore, is `PoisonPill` the right approach? Why not `context.stop` if these are short-lived actors created on the fly?

Have you read the documentation on [throttling](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/howto.html#throttling-messages), as well as [balancing workload across nodes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/howto.html#balancing-workload-across-nodes) or [the work pulling pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/howto.html#work-pulling-pattern-to-throttle-and-distribute-work-and-prevent-mailbox-overflow)?

**Blocking**

Don't! If you *really* have to, use [routers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html) as you suggested.

**Premature Optimisation?**

How have you tested the current solution? Is it proving problematic or showing resource contention? Careful this isn't a case of premature optimisation :)

Of course, the [Akka documentation on best practices](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html) is a great read.